# How to swap a widget inside one container?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to swap widget inside one container. Container will contain list of text or some other elements. I want to swap that list of text one by one within a container

Here is example:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: by swapping one by one you mean you want some kind of animation ?

Comment: You want to swap on some user action?

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-ziG7g3tyzYcfTs6ckSuJ0x1UiRY3Ti3
check this